# How to transform Arraylist data into Vector type？

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, classcastexception, defaulttablemodel

Because I want use `DefaultTableModel` to build a table, the class's params are required `Vector` type. So I try this method to change, but it doesn't work.

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
ArrayList b = new ArrayList();

Vector c = new Vector(a);
Vector d = new Vector(b);

DefaultTableModel tb = new DefaultTableModel(c,d)
```

**Result:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot 
    be cast to java.util.Vector
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Learn to use descriptive variable names and you can save yourself this hassel, almost always

Comment: Use a `for each` to get each value of the array list and add it to the vector. If you cannot get that to work, post a [mcve] of your best attempt. Make sure the variable names are meaningful, as suggested by @smac89.

Comment: The stacktrace would give the source and line number. Check that line. The code given is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you're passing `b`, which is an `ArrayList` to the constructor, instead of `d`, which is its `Vector` counterpart:

```
DefaultTableModel tb = new DefaultTableModel(c, d);
// Here ----------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Sorry,  I make a mistake. My original code is  DefaultTableModel(c, d). Even so, the result is the same.